# Terminal & Windows command to get Android device name along with AVD name

Tags: android, cmd, terminal, adb, emulation

How to get device name along with AVD name

- Created 3 Android Virtual Devices (Android 8, 9 10 versions)
- Started emulators from AVD Manager
- In Terminal window

ADB Command

```
adb devices
```

above command returned output as below

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5556   device
emulator-5558   device
```

And emulator command

```
emulator -list-avds
```

above command returned output as below

```
Pixel_2_XL_API_27
Pixel_2_XL_API_28
Pixel_2_XL_API_29
```

I would like to know which device is attached to each AVD name

Also if I boot AVD in a different order then device name is changing

Example:
if I boot only one emulator Pixel_2_XL_API_28 then emulator-5554 is showing, if I boot the Pixel_2_XL_API_28 after booting Pixel_2_XL_API_29 then emulator-5556 is showing for Pixel_2_XL_API_28

is it possible to associate one device id with one AVD Name?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for you, in python

```
def get_details():
    devices = str(subprocess.check_output("adb devices|grep -|grep device|awk {'print $1'}", shell=True,text=True))
    ans = str.strip(devices).split('\n')    
    port_avd={}
    for emulator in ans:
        port= emulator[-4:]
        p = subprocess.Popen("((sleep 1;echo 'avd name';sleep 1)|telnet localhost " + port + ")|tail -2 ",shell=True,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,text=True)
        port_avd[port] = p.stdout.readline().strip()
        
    return port_avd
```

If you will print the output of this function you'll get a dictionary in the form of

```
{'5554': 'Nexus_5_API_24'}
```

Where key '5554' is from the list of devices and the value is the AVD name, as requested.

**Important Notes:**

- The use of `shell=True` is not secure, you can look it up.
- There might be a more efficient way to do it, since I am initiating a telnet session to get the AVD name.